# ERROR XML: agregando el elemento "task:executor"

Tags: xml, spring

De ante mano gracias por su ayuda, en un archivo XML intento asociar un nuevo elemento asi:

```
<task:executor id="example" pool-size="10"/>
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: ###; columnNumber: ###; El prefijo "task" para el elemento "task:executor" no está enlazado.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando el Xml encontré que faltaba declarar en:

```
xsi:schemaLocation
```

El siguiente fragmento para importar:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
```

y antes de xsi:schemaLocation en los xmlns:XXXX declarar:

```
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
```